# What is the spectrum of a broken square drum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, frequency, boundary-conditions, wavelength, eigenvalue

Given a square drum with sides length equal to $L$, the squared raised frequencies are
$(\pi m/L)^2 + (\pi n/L)^2  $ with $m,n \in \mathbb{N}^*$.
Here we have four boundary conditions (no vibration on the sides).

Suppose that we have only 3 such conditions, what about the spectrum?
We could also have a drum broken on two opposite sides (they could vibrate on these two sides).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you’ll still need to impose boundary conditions on the fourth side. A free side would rather correspond to a Neuman boundary condition. Say your square is $[0,1]^2$ (setting $L=1$), and $u$ the vertical displacement, then you can impose:
$$
\begin{align}
u(x=0)&=0 &u(x=1)&=0 \\
u(y=0)&=0 &\partial_yu(y=1)&=0 \\
\end{align}
$$
with $y=1$ being the free side. This is just the 2D analogue of a string with a free end. You can check that the modes are of the form:
$$
u_{mn}=\sin(\pi mx)\sin(\pi(n+1/2)y)
$$
with angular frequency squared:
$$
\omega_{mn}^2=\pi^2\left(m^2+\left(n+\frac12\right)^2\right)
$$
with $m\in\mathbb N^*$ and $n\in\mathbb N$.

You’ll therefore be able to hear whether all the sides of the drum are clamped.

Hope this helps

Comment: That's it. Three Dirichlet conditions and one Neumann condition.

Comment: Similarly, the spectrum for a square drum with two opposite sides free would be almost the same as that for a square drum with all four sides clamped.  The only difference would be that $n = 0$ would be allowed for the vibrations in the unclamped direction.

Comment: thanks a lot for this clarification.